# Starting a thread when user stops interacting with activity

Tags: android, multithreading

I am working on a contacts app. I have completed its code. Its running fine and does all the things you can ask it to do without any headache. However, there is still chance for improvement. To remove any kind of lag, I load all the contacts image and primary phone numbers before providing any UI to user with a help of a progress dialog. I want to implement a mechanism, so that application starts retrieving a contact image when user is done with scrolling and is searching for/ reading contact names to get the desired one, so the thread should start as soon as user starts reading/or stops scrolling, and it by any chance, he starts scrolling, thread should pause and let user scroll again. Any ideas how it can be achieved as apart from implementing other lag reduction techniques, I believe it would be best. So, any ideas ? I have no clue how to start this mechanism.

Comment: This highly depends on what kind of views you are using, e.g. are you using ScrollView? ListView?

Comment: Sorry for being late.

Yes, I am using list view.

Comment: What about [ListView.setOnScrollListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setOnScrollListener%28android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener%29)?

Comment: Yes. it viable option, but how does I can pause the thread when user srolls again.

Comment: [Thread pools](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using Executors for this instead of Threads. Here's an example - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html